# qgis:refactorfields does not accept @row_number as expression

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-2.18

I *exported* a model from model builder to python. But qgis:refactorfields does not accept @row_number as expression.

```
outputs_QGISREFACTORFIELDS_1=processing.runalg('qgis:refactorfields', outputs_QGISMULTIPARTTOSINGLEPARTS_1['OUTPUT'],'[{'type': 2, 'length': 3, 'expression': u'@row_number', 'name': u'cluster', 'precision': 0}]',cluster)
```

> ```
>       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> 1   Cannot find variable: row_number
> 2   Uncaught error while executing algorithm
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>           File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
>             self.processAlgorithm(progress)
>           File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\script\ScriptAlgorithm.py", line 378, in processAlgorithm
>             exec((script), ns)
>           File "<string>", line 9
> ```

I tried with $row_num, it's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I adapted your script to my system and it worked when I changed this part of code:

```
..., '[{'type': 2, 'length': 3, 'expression': u'@row_number', 'name': u'cluster', 'precision': 0}]', ...
```

in this one:

```
..., [{'type': 2, 'length': 3, 'expression': u'@row_number', 'name': u'cluster', 'precision': 0}], ...
```

My complete code was:

```
import processing

route = iface.activeLayer()

path = outputs_QGISREFACTORFIELDS_1=processing.runalg('qgis:refactorfields', 
                                                      route,
                                                      [{'type': 2, 
                                                      'length': 3, 
                                                      'expression': u'@row_number', 
                                                      'name': u'cluster', 
                                                      'precision': 0}],
                                                      None)

output = QgsVectorLayer(path['OUTPUT_LAYER'],
                        'output',
                        'ogr')

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(output)
```

and produced a result when it was ran at the Python Console of QGIS:

[image]

Comment: Thks, so it s considered as a bug in the ecport to python feature?

Comment: it's the same problem with qgis:fieldcalculator , true and other fields should be between " "

Comment: You're welcome. In relation to your question I don't know. I just tried out your code to find out where the issue was.

Comment: You can see an example of use here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_table_tools.html#refactor-fields and for the **fieldcalculator** here: https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_table_tools.html#field-calculator

Comment: Yes thanks for your answer. I mean a bug about the export module in the model builder. It doesn't export the fields correctly it adds '' or wipe out the " "

Comment: Ok. I got it. However, I've never used model builder. I like to code with PyQGIS.